# Azure IoT hub token format and options

Tags: azure-iot-hub

We have legacy meters that are connected to the cloud and can be configured to send readings to any http endpoint. I can also configure it to add headers such as "Authorization=SharedAccessSignature sr=...".

However, it fails when the header value includes an equal sign ("=").

So the question is, are there any other options for using sas tokens (I cannot use certificates)?

Answer (score -1):

I used Rest Api through .net in my IoT Central app. You can check [here](https://github.com/PankajRawat333/iot-central/blob/a21b2e60bbe5692f1eeb5a144d9347f2cd72fe0a/IoTCentralSimulator/IoTCentralDemo.cs#L51) complete code. I was getting data properly.

*HttpClient Object*

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", getAuth(authScope, reason) + authTarget);

string getAuth(string scope, string target)
    {
        long utcTimeInMilliseconds = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks / 10000;
        long expires = ((utcTimeInMilliseconds + (7200 * 1000)) / 1000);
        string sr = scope + "%2f" + target + "%2f" + deviceId;
        string sigNoEncode = computeHash(deviceKey, sr + '\n' + expires.ToString());
        string sigEncoded = Uri.EscapeDataString(sigNoEncode);
        return "SharedAccessSignature sr=" + sr + "&sig=" + sigEncoded + "&se=" + expires.ToString();
    }
```

hope it will help.

Comment: Thanks but your getAuth method will return a string started with  "SharedAccessSignature sr="... that's the ("-")-sign that screws it up for me :(